# Can't Mirror Bone Roll When X-axis Mirror is turned on, bones snap to other side & overlap

Tags: rigging, bones, mirror

I have the left half of an armature, all properly named with prefixes. With both 3D cursor and Pivot pint in center, I mirror my armature using ctrl-m, x. I flip the names correctly. Then I invert my selection, to select the original half of the armature, and then turn on x-axis mirror. Here is a screenshot of my mirrored, and name-flipped armature:[image]

Here, I press ctrl-r to rotate bone roll. In many youtube tutorials, this forces the mirrored side to match the original side's bone roll exactly. Unfortunately for me, all it does is snap my mirrored side over to my original side. I do not have snapping turned on, it is off. What can I do to precisely mirror both side's positions and bone rolls? Below is a screenshot of what happens when I press ctrl-r:
[image]
I cannot be the only one who's had this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who's also had this problem: you need to apply scale and rotation to your armature in object mode. Once you apply these, then go into edit mode and mirror your armature. X-axis mirror should then perfectly match the bone rolls if you press ctrl-r and press enter without moving the mouse.